# BufferedWriter causes Memory Exceed exception

Tags: java

I am using BufferedWriter to write my content to a file. [Actually file is is HDFS. I am writing through reducer.]

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    Path path = new Path("temp.txt");       
    OutputStream os = fs.create(path);
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
```

This is how I am creating BufferedWriter.[**SetUp method of the reducer**.]

Writing Part in the **reduce method**:

```
try {
        bufferedWriter.write(dt+ExporterConstants.MAP_OUTPUT_KEY_SEPERATOR+hdfsPath+ExporterConstants.MAP_OUTPUT_KEY_SEPERATOR+inputSplit+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I am closing this method in the **clean up method of the reducer**

**My Question:**

I am getting error like `container is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used; 8.7 GB of 11.5 GB virtual memory used`. So What I am assuming is I am buffering all the data and flushing it only once at the time of close method.

Is it causing the issue?
And How do I flush efficiently?

And I am open to use other writers also. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the heap size is too large for the memory you have given it. The JVM can use the maximum heap size trying to make your program run faster, not just due to retained data.

Try reducing the memory consumption of the JVM. If you make it too low for the data it is retaining it will get an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @GopsAB what is your doubt? I can't think of a simpler way of putting it, I am sorry.